# Powershell Net.HttpWebRequest returns "Getresponse with 0 arguments"

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a small script that retrieves a website's SSL's expiring date.

here's the code:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
$timeoutMilliseconds = 10000
$req = $null
$req = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create("https://google.com")
$req.Timeout = $timeoutMilliseconds
$req.GetResponse();
$expiration = $req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString()
$expiration
```

This works exactly twice(!) before throwing a "Getresponse with 0 arguments".
If I re-open powershell it'll work again exactly 2 times.
I'm unsure what's going on here...

Comment: you put this script in profile.ps1 ? do you want another script check ssl validity or just improve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it runs 2 times and then fails. However, if you add

```
$req.Abort()
```

after the last line of the snippet you showed it will work every time. Be careful though, if that code snippet is incomplete and you are doing things with $req after that snippet then calling the abort method may cause some exceptions to be thrown.